# How to fetch messages which are uncommited in kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a function in java in which I am trying to fetch messages which are unread. For example, If I have messages with offSet 0,1,2 in broker which are already read by the consumer and If I switch off my consumer for an hour. And at that time I produce messages with offset 3,4,5. After that when my consumer is started it should read message from offset 3 not from 0. But, It either reads all the messages or read those messages which are produced after starting Kafka consumer. I want to read those messages which are unread or uncommited

I tried `"auto.offset.reset"= "latest"` and `"earliest"`. as well as `"enable.auto.commit" = "true"` and `"false"`. I also tried `commitSync()` and `commitAsync()` before calling `close()` method but no luck.

```
public static KafkaConsumer createConsumer() {

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, Constants.KAFKA_BROKER);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "testGroup");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest"); 
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "50");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "1");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);

    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);

    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(Constants.TOPIC));
    return consumer;

}
```

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("----------------");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("KAFKA CONSUMER EXAMPLE");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("----------------");
    System.out.println("");

    OffsetAndMetadata offsetAndMetadataInitial = createConsumer().committed(new TopicPartition(Constants.TOPIC, 0));

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Offset And MetaData Initial : ");
    System.out.println(offsetAndMetadataInitial);
    System.out.println("");

    ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = createConsumer().poll(Duration.ofSeconds(2L));

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Count Consumer Records : " + consumerRecords.count());
    System.out.println("");

    Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> itr = consumerRecords.iterator();
    Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> partationOffsetMap = new HashMap<>(4);

    while (itr.hasNext()) {

        ConsumerRecord record = itr.next();

        System.out.println("OffSet : " + record.offset());
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Key : " + record.key());
        System.out.println("Value : " + record.value());
        System.out.println("Partition : " + record.partition());
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        System.out.println("");

    }



    createConsumer().close();

}
```

I just want to fetch only unread messages in kafka Consumer. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere. And Thanks in Advance

Comment: I believe you are confusing "uncommitted" with "unread" messages. As far as I understand you want to consume unread messages (i.e. offsets), that have already been committed to the topic. Is that correct?

Comment: Make sure that the next time you're starting your consumer, you use the same consumer group name.

If the above is valid, then due to some reason, your last read message offset is not getting committed. Could you check via kafka console, if the topic consumer_offsets is getting created and if it is getting new messages when you commit? If not, let us investigate further.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous was considering "uncommited" and "unread" to be same.As according to my understanding commited messages are those which are processed by Consumer and uncommited are those which are not processed(unread) by Kafka Consumer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that you are not closing the consumer you used to poll messages; this is because each call to createConsumer() creates a new KafkaConsumer. And as you are not closing the consumer, and are calling poll() only once, you never commit the messages you have read.

(with auto-commit, commit is called within poll() after auto-commit-interval, and within close())

Once you will have corrected that it should work with following settings:

- auto-commit=true (otherwise you could also commit manually, but auto-commit is simpler).
- offset-reset= earliest (this has only effect the first time you consume for a given group-id, to tell if you want to consume from the begining of the topic or only messages produced after you started to consume. Once you have started to consume with a given group-id, you will always continue to consume from the latest offset you have committed.)
- group-id must not change between restarts, or you will start from the begining or from the end again depending on your offset-reset setting.

Hope this helps

Comment: @pgrs Thanks for your help, It was a silly mistake. I didn't noticed that createConsumer().close() method is doing its action on new Kafka Consumer Object.